# Spartacus Backend OCC login endpoint change

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I have a question regarding the possibility to change the backend occ endpoint for the login.

[image]

In the default behavior, an `auth` object is created in local storage.

I changed in the `app.module` the default `login: '/authorizationserver/oauth/token'`, to a different endpoint `(/ourowntestserver/oath/token/test)`. After the change, the backend-side works as it has before, but on the front-end side, the `auth` object is not available in the local storage anymore.

In the Spartacus source code I can see an `OAUTH_ENDPOINT` with the same endpoint  `'/authorizationserver/oauth/token'`, used in an `open-id-token.service`, but I am not sure if that service is responsible for actually saving the token and if I have to extend it in the storefront app along with its `store(actions, effects, etc.)` too.

Are there any other changes that have to be done for this to work, or am I doing something wrong? Is it possible that the issue could be still back-end related?

Any help would be appreciated. (edited)

Answer (score 0):

I would start by inspecting ngrx actions in devtools. Look for `LoadUserToken` and `LoadUserTokenSuccess` and `LoadUserTokenFail` actions. Look at their payload if everything there looks ok. Maybe the structure of response is different than the one returned from the default hybris OAuth server. Then you might need to create your own effect and handle the response a bit different than we do this by default.

The `OAUTH_ENDPOINT` is not currently customizable and it is being fixed right now for the 3.0 release. It'll have new auth module structure and allow for easier replacement of OAuth server.

`open-id-token.service.ts` is only used with Kyma module when you also need apart from `access_token` the `id_token` from OAuth server.